# Invalid cast exception where using Enum as data source to DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I am converting enum to `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` in my controller in order to use it in `DropDownListFor` helper.

```
var roleList = EnumHelper.GetSelectList(typeof(UserRole))
           .Cast<UserRole>()
           .Except(new UserRole[] { UserRole.Admin, UserRole.Corporate })
           .Select(e => new SelectListItem { Text = e.ToString(), Value = ((int)e).ToString() });
ViewBag.SelectList = roleList;
```

and my razor code looks like

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RoleID, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.SelectList)
```

but I am getting an error

> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

To make sure it is a valid cast I checked datatype of `roleList` in controller and it looks fine as shown below

[image: cast error]

during run time I ensured that `ViewBag.SelectList` is not null by debugging and there is no issues

[image: Debug mode]

but when I expand the result I get error message

[image: error finally]

Comment: Well, I guess when you tried to cast enum as int in `(int)e` there's the problem raised. I believe you are trying to cast `abc` as `int` there. Parse it as string and re-run

Comment: @Shahjahan Thanks for the comment. I tried and it still doesn't work.  (int)Enum.Member gives integer value from enum.

Comment: have you tried: `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RoleID, ViewBag.SelectList)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EnumHelper.GetSelectList` returns `IList<SelectListItem>` and then `Cast<UserRole>()` throws an exception because it cannot cast `SelectListItem` to `UserRole`. In order to get all `enum` values use `Enum.GetValues`

```
var roleList = Enum.GetValues(typeof(UserRole))
       .Cast<UserRole>()
       .Except(new UserRole[] { UserRole.Admin, UserRole.Corporate })
       .Select(e => new SelectListItem { Text = e.ToString(), Value = ((int)e).ToString() });
```